# Relational Table design

Tags: sql, database, database-design, rdbms

I am designing a feature for a database, but I am stuck on design.

I have a table called AgendaItems, this table is a table with Agenda Items that could be assign to possible multiple users.

Users is a table that contains a record of user names, containing a fixed amount of 17 names.

How would I design these tables possibly another table that keeps track of who is working on what Agenda Item. Keep in mind multiple users could work on an agenda Item and users could work on multiple items.

I am not sure who to design this, and wondering if it would even work?

Thanks

Comment: Create a linking table, UserAgendas, with FK UserID and FK AgendaID from your other tables.  Link from Users to UserAgendas on UserID, then to AgendaItems on AgendaID

Comment: The user association is to the agendaitem not just the agenda.

Comment: Read up on many to many relationships.  This case is one of the database design fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your problem but I think your relationship is N-N.
So, you need to create another table (UsersAgendaItems). This table must contain the AgendaItems ID and Users ID, where both of then are FK.
Your PK could be a composite PK. This way you can know what user is related with what AgendaItems.

But I don't know if that is what you want. If this is not your case, please, try to explain a little bit more!
Thanks!

Comment: Better to ask for clarifications in comments than to shotgun answers.